# How to write wait in Selenium web Driver until values get filled in drop down and then click on a button

Tags: java, selenium

In my application when i opens a page a dropdown displays and then i need to click on a proceed button. Problem is drop down takes some time to load the values but in my code it click before the drop down loads.I tried with implicit wait and thread.sleep but it some time it work and some time doesn't work.
Code:

```
       public class Home {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
    {
    File file1 = new File("C:\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.35.3\\IEDriverServer.exe");
      System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file1.getAbsolutePath());

   WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.get("http://10.120.13.100/");

     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    Thread.sleep(3000);

    WebElement clickBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("btnHomeProceed"));
   clickBtn.click();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [FluentWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html)

```
final Select droplist = new Select(driver.findElement(By.Id("selection")));
new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
        .withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .pollingEvery(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .until(new Predicate<WebDriver>() {

            public boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                return (!droplist.getOptions().isEmpty());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Karna, I am trying with fluent wait as well but code shows this error "Cannot refer to a non-final variable droplist inside an inner class defined in a different method"  near the line "return (!droplist.getOptions().isEmpty());"

Comment: @Huma: Just mark `droplist` as final. I have added it in my answer

Answer (score 2):

Using Proper X.path reaching into the option can be easy solution here.  Try the following code.

`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//select[@name='Location']/option[@value='1']")));`

This will see if element in option has been loaded, if not it will wait until it is loaded into DOM for given seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this same problem some time ago. This is my solution working with Java 8:

```
    void selectTextFromDropDown(final By locator, final String value, final int timeoutInSeconds) {
    FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = createWait(timeoutInSeconds);
    wait.until(input -> {
        Select mySelect = new Select(input.findElement(locator));
        List<WebElement> options = mySelect.getOptions();
        for (WebElement option : options) {
            if (option.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                option.click();
                mySelect.getAllSelectedOptions().contains(value.toLowerCase());
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `wait()` and `notify()` methods.
The place you have written `Thread.sleep()` method, replace it with `this.wait()`.
And the place where the load data of your dropdown is completed put there `this.notify()`method.
I hope this will help u.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you want.

```
for (int second = 0;; second++) {
    if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
    try { 
        Select droplist = new Select(driver.findElement(By.Id("selection")));
        if(!droplist.getOptions().isEmpty()){
            break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
         // best put something here
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: Hi BenvnQ, I tried this but am getting following Waring on the code page " The method fail(String) is undefined for the type Home" .Home is my class name.

Comment: fail is an static assert method provided by junit you can do a static import to get it. If you are not using junit you could replace with a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like the following:

```
//To type text in drop down 
driver.findElement(By.id("ur id")).sendKeys("txt");

//Use implicit wait to load the drop down
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(250, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)

//Then click on the value in the drop down
new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[@class='ui-menu-item'][5]"))).click()

//Now click the next drop down after clicking the drop down value
driver.findElement(By.className("buttonname")).click()
```